# CUDA on Wayland? (just computation, no graphics)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, wayland

I have a setup with an integrated Intel GPU and a dedicated Nvidia GPU. I'm trying to continue using Wayland (using the Intel GPU) while keeping the dedicated Nvidia card reserved purely for computation (some ML stuff).

I already have Nvidia's proprietary drivers installed, so everything is fine (as I would expect) when I use X11. Commands like `nvidia-smi` work flawlessly. But, when I switch to Wayland, the card only has its name shown in my system information. Other than that it's as if it doesn't exist. This is what `nvidia-smi` shows, for example:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

although the card is detected in `lshw`:

```
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
                configuration: depth=32 latency=0 mode=3840x2400 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2400
```

Are there any workarounds, considering that I **DO NOT** want to use the GPU for the display?

Comment: Wayland breaks GPU drivers.  Your Intel card requires fully function NVidia graphics because that is how it switches from CUDA/NVIDIA to the Intel CPU powered graphics.  Disable Wayland if you intend to do this.  Or, if you don't intend to use a GUI at all, install Server instead and install your drivers there accordingly.

Comment: What computation doesn't work?  Without graphics, the cuda samples have many computation-only samples, like simpleOccupancy, which compiles and runs just fine under Wayland.